# How to make the first carousel slider full screen like the second one?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

I have the first carousel slider fiddle example and I need to make it look like second carousel slider I have, the difference between the two carousels is that the first carousel has better transition effects than the second which I have implemented in my study website.

What I need is to make the example 1 carousel:

[image: 1]

to look like the example 2 carousel:

[image: 2]

(full screen responsive) I have uploaded the examples to a demo website so you can play with the values of elements in inspection tool of chrome or Mozilla at f12, I also will post detailed code with comments so you can understand what code does

[here is the demo website so you can see the 2 examples](https://imprecise-seasons.000webhostapp.com/)

I am using the free websites from hostinger.com which is 000webhost.com ( to display test sites as fiddles) ( you perhaps will see this error which is a false positive cause the website is not phishing, not even scam not even malware it is just plain html with CSS and js) I already reported to Google the false positive:

[image]

what I need is the first slider to look like the second slider (full screen) I will show you the approach I have tried so you can save time.

as I am not very experienced on this what I tried at first is to use the code used in #home id, in the example 2

[image]

applying to the example slider 1 CSS, since by logic I assume due to the lack of html code for display the slider #2 the code taking part in the resize and width of the image is this and should have worked on slider #1, but it did not work:

```
/* Home section */

 #home {
        color: #ffffff;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
      }
    
      #home .gradient-overlay {
      background: #c21500; /* fallback for old browsers */  
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #c21500 , #ffc500); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(to left, #c21500 , #ffc500); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
      opacity: 0.4;      
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

having this result

[image]

[image: the result]

I will leave a link to the CSS code and js code so you can see what it does

image slider CSS and image slider js are the ones which control the first example slider(which I am trying to leave as the example 2 (full screen responsive banner, because what I need is to have the same slider but with the transition effects of the number 1))
[img slider CSS](https://imprecise-seasons.000webhostapp.com/themes/1/js-image-slider.css)

in image slider CSS I also have the CSS code which controls the second slider

here is the code snippet in image slider CSS which controls the second slider:

```
/* Home section */
     #home {
        color: #ffffff;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
      }
    
      #home .gradient-overlay {
      background: #c21500; /* fallback for old browsers */  
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #c21500 , #ffc500); /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
      background: linear-gradient(to left, #c21500 , #ffc500); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
      opacity: 0.4;      
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

here is the CSS code of the first slider example:

```
#sliderFrame, #sliderFrame div {
        box-sizing: content-box;
    }
    #sliderFrame 
    {
        width:700px;
        margin:0 auto; /*center-aligned*/
    }
    
    #slider, #slider .sliderInner {
        width:700px;/* Must be the same size as the slider images */
        border-radius:3px;
    
        color: #ffffff;
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
            -ms-flex-align: center;
              align-items: center;
        text-align: center;
        height: 100vh;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
    }
    
    #slider {
        background-color:white;
        position:relative;
        margin:0 auto; /*center-aligned*/
        transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
        box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;
    }
    
    /* the link style (if an image is wrapped by a link) */
    #slider a.imgLink, #slider .video {
        z-index:2;
        cursor:pointer;
        position:absolute;
        top:0px;left:0px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;
        width:100%;height:100%;
    }
    #slider .video {
        background:transparent url(video.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    }
    
    /* Caption styles */
    #slider .mc-caption {
        position:absolute;
        width:100%;
        height:auto;
        padding:10px 0;/* 10px will increase the height.*/
        left:0px;
        bottom:0px;top:auto;
        overflow:hidden;
        font: bold 14px/20px Arial;
        color:#EEE;
        text-align:center;
        background:rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }
    #slider .mc-caption a {
        color:#FB0;
    }
    #slider .mc-caption a:hover {
        color:#DA0;
    }
    
    
    /* ------ built-in navigation bullets wrapper ------*/
    #slider .navBulletsWrapper  {
        top:320px;
        text-align:center;
        background:none;
        position:relative;
        z-index:3;
    }
    
    /* each bullet */
    #slider .navBulletsWrapper div 
    {
        width:11px; height:11px;
        font-size:0;color:White;/*hide the index number in the bullet element*/
        background:transparent url(bullet.png) no-repeat 0 0;
        display:inline-block; *display:inline; zoom:1;
        overflow:hidden;cursor:pointer;
        margin:0 6px;/* set distance between each bullet*/
    }
    
    #slider .navBulletsWrapper .active {background-position:0 -11px;}
    
    
    /* --------- Others ------- */
    
    #slider img, #slider>b, #slider a>b {
        position:absolute; border:none; display:none;
    }
    
    #slider .sliderInner {
        overflow:hidden;
        position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
    }
    
    #slider>a, #slider video, #slider audio {display:none;}
    #slider div {-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);transform: translate3d(0,0,0);}
    
    div.navBulletsWrapper  {display:none;}
```

here is the link to custom js which controls the second slider
[here](https://imprecise-seasons.000webhostapp.com/themes/1/custom.js)

as you can see in [index html](https://view-source:https://imprecise-seasons.000webhostapp.com/)

I am using the following JavaScript files which are used in the second example called in [custom js](https://imprecise-seasons.000webhostapp.com/themes/1/custom.js):

```
backstretch,
jquery,
jquery.backstretch.min,
jquery.magnific-popup.min,
jquery.parallax,wow.min
```

those files are not used in the first example, the only js used in the first example is a function created by the demo 1 [demo 1 example 1 js file](https://imprecise-seasons.000webhostapp.com/themes/1/js-image-slider.js)

```
<link href="themes/1/js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="themes/1/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="generic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="themes/1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="themes/1/jquery.backstretch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="themes/1/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="themes/1/jquery.parallax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="themes/1/nivo-lightbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="themes/1/wow.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="themes/1/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I will leave here the  html code of the [demo website](https://imprecise-seasons.000webhostapp.com/)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Demo 1 - Menucool Image Slider</title>
    <link href="themes/1/js-image-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="themes/1/js-image-slider.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="generic.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="themes/1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="themes/1/jquery.backstretch.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="themes/1/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="themes/1/jquery.parallax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="themes/1/nivo-lightbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="themes/1/wow.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="themes/1/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="div1"><h2>Demo 1 - Menucool Image Slider</h2>
        <p>Demos: <a href="demo1.html" class="current">1</a><a href="demo2.html">2</a><a href="demo3.html">3</a><a href="demo4.html">4</a>
        <a href="demo5.html">5</a><a href="demo6.html">6</a><a href="demo7.html">7</a><a href="demo8.html">8</a></p>
    </div>
    <div id="sliderFrame">
        <div id="slider">
            <a href="http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider" target="_blank">
                <img src="images/image-slider-1.jpg" alt="Welcome to Menucool.com" />
            </a>
            <img src="images/image-slider-2.jpg" />
            <img src="images/image-slider-3.jpg" alt="" />
            <img src="images/image-slider-4.jpg" alt="#htmlcaption" />
            <img src="images/image-slider-5.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div id="htmlcaption" style="display: none;">
            <em>HTML</em> caption. Link to <a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>.
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div2">
        <ul>
            <li><b>Copy & Paste</b>: Copy source code and paste it into your own page. All source codes/files are within the <i>demo1.html</i> and the "<i>\themes\1\</i>" folder</li>
            <li><b>Transitional effects</b>: You can choose from 17 transitional effects via the <i>sliderOptions</i> in the <em>js-image-slider.js</em>. 
            Visit <a href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/javascript-image-slider-demo1" target="_blank">Image Slider Demo 1</a> to see how each effect looks and how to customize</li>
            <li><b>Navigation Bullets</b>: Navigation bullets are created automatically by the script of the image slider.
            <p>The CSS class selector <span class="green">.navBulletsWrapper</span> can be used to change the nav bullets' position and style.</p>
            <p>If you don't need the Navigation Bullets, just hide them via CSS:<br /><span class="green cn">div.navBulletsWrapper  {display:none;}</span></p>
            </li>
            <li><b>HTML Caption</b>: Captions are set through each slide image's <span class="cn">alt</span> attribute. If the caption contains HTML content, 
            you can put the content inside a DIV or SPAN element(usually styled as <span class="cn">display:none</span>), give the element an ID,
            and set the <span class="cn">alt</span> as "#(the content container's id)". For example: <span class="cn">alt="#caption4"</span></li>
            <li>The image slider shown in this demo is for free.</li>
            <li>For detailed instructions, please visit online <a href="http://www.menucool.com/slider/javascript-image-slider-demo1">Demo 1</a> and 
            <a href="http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider" target="_blank">JavaScript Image Slider</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>



    <section id="home">
        <div class="gradient-overlay"></div>
          <div class="container">
            
          </div>
      </section>




</body>
</html>
```

what could I do to make the first slider to look exactly like the second slider but with the same transitions of the first example?

Comment: so you want the entire slider to be covering the entire screen and be responsive at the same time with a an effect of the first example . Am I understanding this right?

Comment: @swm your question is not clear, try to focus in the main feature you need

Comment: i need the first slider to be full screen like the second one and be responsive, tried and failed that is why i am here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first slider `mcImgSlider` which has nice transition effects is [javascript-image-slider](http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider) is developed by menucool.com. And it is a licensed product. 
The transition effects have been achieved using JavaScript and it's not CSS only implementation.
As per their documentation:

> Note: All slider images should have the same size, and the slider should be set to that size.

> The slider image is not scalable as the images in this slider will be used as the background of the sliced DIVs, and the background image cannot be scaled.

There is only one way to change entire slider size is to edit and increase sizes of
all images. And it is not responsive at all.

---

You are better off using free opensource sliders available on GitHub. Like [Flux Slider](https://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/)

```js
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
$(function() {
  window.myFlux = new flux.slider('#slider', {
    autoplay: true,
    transitions: ['blocks2', 'zip', 'blinds', 'tiles3d']
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#slider {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-size: cover;
}

#slider * {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 100% !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.joelambert.co.uk/flux/js/flux.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider">
  <img src="https://imprecise-seasons.000webhostapp.com/images/image-slider-2.jpg">
  <img src="https://imprecise-seasons.000webhostapp.com/images/image-slider-3.jpg">
  <img src="https://imprecise-seasons.000webhostapp.com/images/image-slider-4.jpg">
  <img src="https://imprecise-seasons.000webhostapp.com/images/image-slider-5.jpg">
</div>
```

Switch to 'full page'. 
It is [customizable](https://github.com/joelambert/Flux-Slider#setup) play with it.

Comment: How about `background-size: cover;` for `#slider *`?